# How to create a custom tab with custom attributes in Customer admin

Tags: magento2, forms, eav, tabs

I am a beginner in Magento (version 2.3).

I am looking for a solution to create a form with custom attributes, which would be displayed by clicking on a custom tab in Customer admin.

I have understood how to create a custom attribute and have seen how to create a new tab.

The problem I encounter is how to join these two?

I saw my attribute can be `used_in_forms`. Should I create a new form here? In this case, how to create and render the form?

Thank you for your help,

Jeremy

Comment: you want to make a custom tab in customer edit section right? in admin side

Comment: @AdarshShukla yes exactly

Comment: ok wait i will answer you in am moment

Comment: check answer if any issue comment

Comment: Thanks! There is still one thing I cannot understand, it is how to do to render eav attributes in this form. Does it need to be done manually in the phtml template? How is it achieved by Magento when I add an eav attribute in the `customer_account_edit` form?

Comment: what you want exactly render?? have you added custom attribute in customer

Comment: Let say I add an EAV attribute and don't want it to be append in "Account Information" but in another tab. How sould I do?

Comment: have you added your attribute by install Script??

Comment: Yes, my EAV attribute is added by an UpgradeData script on `customer` entity type. Currently, I can see this attribute (which is working) in "Account Information" tab.

Comment: use object manager     $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$customer->getCustomAttribute('authnet_account_number')->getValue();

Comment: this will shurely help you if helped please Accept answer and upvote...

Comment: authnet_account_number is name of your custom attribute

Comment: did my answer worked

Comment: Do I have to render, populate and process the form (with the EAV attribute) by my self? Is it possible to reuse some code (the same code used by Magento to append my EAV attribute to `customer_account_edit` form) to render automatically the EAV attribute in my own form in the new tab?

Comment: I didn't got you can you elaborate?

Comment: The main problem I encounter is to render a custom EAV attribute in the newly created tab for customer edit admin. You explained how to create a tab, what I cannot understand is how to render a form with my EAV attribute? Can it be rendered automatically (like it is when I add it to `customer_account_edit` form)?

Comment: render meaning you just want to echo custom attribute on tab right ?

Comment: Yes, I mean printing some html in the view. Does it need to be done manually or is there some code I can reuse from Magento, since it is an EAV attribute?

Comment: you need to write phtml file as mentioned in step 3 of answer and phtml contain all your design of tab please refere step 3 of my answer

Comment: have you solved issue ??

Comment: if solved upvote also..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88344/discussion-on-question-by-jargoud-how-to-create-a-custom-tab-with-custom-attribu).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step 1:Create app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml File

with block decleration

**Step 2:Create app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/View.php File**
content of View.php

class View extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'tab/customer_view.phtml';

```
/**
 * View constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getCustomerId()
{
    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(\Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('Custom Tab');
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('Custom Tab');
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Tab class getter
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabClass()
{
    return '';
}

/**
 * Return URL link to Tab content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabUrl()
{
    return '';
}

/**
 * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAjaxLoaded()
{
    return false;
}
```

}

**step 3:create app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/tab/customer_view.phtml with Your desin logic and if you want to pass some data use block file code**

get referance from [here](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-tab-in-admin-customer-edit-page-in-magento-2/)